# Prevent data binding in invisible asp.net panel

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

A hidden (`visible="false"`) panel is not rendered, but data binding is executed on contained elements. Why is that done? And more important, how to avoid it?

Here is an example where it is annoying:

```
<asp:Panel ID="UserPanel" runat="server" visible="<%# SelectedUser != null %>">
    <%# SelectedUser.Name %>
</asp:Panel>
```

If `SelectedUser` is `null`, the panel is not rendered but `SelectedUser.Name` is evaluated and generates an error.

I could obviously write `<%# SelectedUser != null ? SelectedUser.Name : "" %>` but it adds clutter.

Is there a way to simply and elegantly prevent data binding within a panel when I know it is not needed?

The `Panel` control is not important here, it could be a Placeholder of a plain HTML element with `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I may be late on this one but I also find this very annoying.

I need this often if I am rendering a list of items where each item may be a different class - in which case the properties in the data binding expressions will give errors in the invisible sections intended for other class types. You'll know if you want this.

The best solution I have found is described here:

http://hermanussen.eu/sitecore/wordpress/2011/04/prevent-nullrefs-when-databinding-with-placeholders/

The solution is a simple override of the standard PlaceHolder control to suppress binding child controls if Visible is false:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace Website.Controls
{ 
    public class DataPlaceHolder : PlaceHolder 
    { 
        protected override void DataBindChildren() 
        { 
            if (Visible) 
            { 
                base.DataBindChildren(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Adding `DataPlaceHolder`s is not a high price to pay and everything remains readable. I would prefer another name for that class though.

Comment: How do I stop a two-way binding? (BindItem).  If I put a textbox inside this DataPlcaeHolder with visible = false. Upon the update method, it still get bind and get the value null.

Comment: Fantastic solution that helped me to speed up a project with tons of controls, many of them having data bind related events defined and with only a few of these controls being visible at pageload.

Comment: One attention point (based on my experience): Visible properties depends on Visible property of parent controls. So if you have a binding expression for Visible of DataPlaceHolder Control evaluated to `true`, but it has a Parent control with `Visible = false` then DataPlaceHolder.Visible will be `false`. So first set <<ParentControl>>.Visible to `true` then DataBind(); the opposite will give you wrong results.