# Panel is Invisible but children are databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, overriding

I have panel in an ASP.NET control. When it is invisible all the `GridViews` in the `Panel` are databinding. I don't want them to when the `Panel` is invisible. The following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261275/prevent-data-binding-in-invisible-asp-net-panel) was presented. It is a good solution for `Placeholders` and I have tried to implement it for `Panels`

```
public class NewPanel : Panel
{
    protected override void DataBindChildren()
    {
        if (visible)
        {
            base.DataBindChildren();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how do I now use the NewPanel class in the markup in the .aspx page ?
Or is there a way to just override the method in `Panel`in the code dynamically and just keep using `Panel` in the markup ?

This is a portion of the aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="AssignedGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="OrderID" DataSourceID="AssignedDS" Width="100%">
      <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created" SortExpression="DateOrderCreated">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOrderCreated", "{0:d-MMM-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AssignedDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXXXX %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT T_Orders.OrderID, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX OrderQuoteVersion.RequestApprovalOfEmployeeID, T_Orders.JobNumber FROM XXXXXXX AS T_OrderQuoteVersion RIGHT OUTER JOIN XXXXX AS T_Orders INNER JOIN XXXXXXX ON T_Orders.CustomerID = T_Customers.CustomerID ON T_OrderQuoteVersion.OrderID = T_Orders.OrderID  "></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This code is within the Panel and gets databinded regardless if the Panel is invisible or not

Comment: How are you currently data binding? Are you using SQLDataSource Controls or using the C# code behind page? Could you also include your current, relevant ASPX markup?

Comment: I have included the relevant code. Yes I am using SqlDataSource Controls.

Answer (score 1):

I normally databind in the code behind and I will use that approach here as I find it gives you more control. I'll be interested in seeing any answers that maintain the use of the `SQLDataSource` control.

The only change you need to make to your aspx is to remove the `SQLDataSource` control.

In your code behind you'll want something like

```
//Put this in PageLoad or Load, what ever suits you best
//The IsPostBack check is optional....remove it if that fits tour needs better
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    //Use the Appropriate Panel ID below
    if(PanelID.Visible)
    {
        string constring = "Your Connection String";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("YOUR SQL QUERY", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
               {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        AssignedGV.DataSource = dt;
                        AssignedGV.DataBind();
                    }
               }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

**Note** I haven't tested the code, it may have typos or other stupid errors but it should be enough to get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Although your solution is good and works I am going to pursue a SqlDataSource solution because I am editing lots of code that is already written. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you find a solution elsewhere, make sure to post it up here so we can all benefit from your success. There is nothing wrong with accepting your own answer should you find one.